# How to create MooTools class of a variable name

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2

Consider this code:

```
var Someclass = new Class();
var Anotherclass = new Class();
var classes = ['Someclass', 'Anotherclass'];
```

and I want to create mootools class with a dynamic name.
Of course i can do it by eval:

```
eval('var obj = new ' + classes[0] + '(params);');
```

but I do not think it is a good solution.
How to do this in a "proper" way?
Maybe somethink like:

```
var obj = ObjectFactory(classes[0], params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to refer to the class as a string.

```
var object = new window['SomeClass']();
```

Pass it parameters as regular.

```
var object = new window['SomeClass'](1, 2, "three");
```

Instead of creating all classes globally, use an object to namespace them.

```
var My = {
    SomeClass: new Class(..),
    OtherClass: new Class(..)
};

var object = new My['SomeClass']();
```